# iTunes connect app transfer issue

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I am having hard time to transfer application. It shows TestFlight beta testing criteria not matching. But I already removed all builds and test information from TestFlight. I have same issue in my two different iTunes account. If anyone have solution for this then please let me know.
I already contacted apple support but no reply from them since one week.

Enclosed are screenshots of my account status of TestFlight and app transfer page.
[image]

Comment: This seems to be an issue from Apple server.But you can try again with uploading a new build & turn off beta testing.
Otherwise you can raise Technical Support Issue from your developer's account.If this would be an issue from their end they will credit TSI back into your account.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you removed all the information, **in all languages**. It worked for me.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5cKj.png)